# Authenticating into website using Ji, NSUrlSessions?

Tags: swift, authentication, nsurlsession

Hey I'm using the Ji library to try and pass a form so I can login to this website. I'm pretty new to this and have never done authentication before. I've found the form where I can place the ID and Password, I just don't know how to change the value and submit. This is what I have so far.

```
import UIKit
import Ji


class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mistarTitle: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mistar = Ji(htmlURL: URL(string: "https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/studentportal/")!)
    let titleNode = mistar?.xPath("//head/title")?.first
    print("title: \(titleNode!.content)") 

    mistarTitle.text = titleNode!.value

    // Finding ID Node
    let bodyDivNode = mistar?.xPath("//body/div/div")?.first
    let idNodeNext = bodyDivNode?.nextSibling?.xPath("//div/form/div/div").first
    let next = idNodeNext?.nextSibling?.xPath("//table").dropFirst().first
    let nextTr = idNodeNext?.xPath("//tr").dropFirst().first
    let firstID = nextTr?.nextSibling?.xPath("td").dropFirst().first
    let inputID = firstID?.xPath("input").first

    print(inputID?.attributes)

    // Finding PassWord Node

    let firstPass = next?.children.dropFirst().dropFirst().first
    let firstP = firstPass?.xPath("td").dropFirst().first
    let inputPW = firstP?.xPath("input").first

    print(inputPW?.attributes)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to manipulate the form on the page directly, why not try sending the HTTP request with code?

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Look at the web page you're trying to post to, and then check out the HTTP headers using chrome or whatever your browser is. Should give you some info on it.